# Achieving this layout while staying responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a layout that uses a fixed side bar that takes up about `20%` of a screen, the other `80%` is a long vertical scroll.

```
+------+------------------------+
|  F   |          S             |
|  I   |          C             |
|  X   |          R             |
|  E   |          O             |
|  D   |          L             |
|      |          L             |
+------+------------------------+
```

Right now I have it set up using something like this:

```
<div class="menu"> ... </div>
<div class="content"> ... </div>
```

Then I style them like this:

```
.menu{
  background: #f6f6f6;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content{
display: block;
    width: 77%;
    height: 4000px;
    float: left;
    left: 208px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Now although this does work, it does lend well to responsive. Since they are `absolute` and `fixed` they create a border on the side as it enlarges. 
What are my options to achieve this layout?

**[Current Demo](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/vNNRpo/)**, apologies for messy code.

Comment: You can use css media/screen size queries to use different css for every resolution. That should easily solve all your problems.

Comment: I was planning to use them for when I had to switch to mobile. But I was looking for a solution where I could keep it `80%`/`20%` throughout a couple screen sizes without touching media queries.

Comment: I can see a width given to the left-menu and right-section. Simply remove the width from right-section, it will cover up the remaining space of the screen. Check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zbbxwo.

Comment: Add a few breakpoints, so you can trigger some Media Queries...

Comment: @KunjanThadani perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/a0my545L/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{margin: 0px;} 
.div-1{
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.div-2{
    background: red;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    height: 4000px;
    float: left;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```